# Is there dataloss from converting from varchar to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, encoding, varchar, nvarchar

I have a column in SQL Server that is `varchar(MAX)`. The column has been populated with that data type. I now want to convert the column to `nvarchar(MAX)` to accept unicode characters.

Is there any data loss when I convert this column from `varchar(MAX)` to `nvachhar(MAX)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every character that can be represented in `varchar` is also representable in `nvarchar`.

The only possible data loss issue would be if you have any `varchar(max)` values that are already greater than 1GB.

In most collations `nvarchar` uses 2 bytes per character and `varchar` uses 1 byte per character. Doubling the string length of a string > 1 GB would obviously take you over the 2GB limit.

Even then I would expect an error message rather than silent truncation but possibly it might silently fail under some settings such as `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`.

Comment: So just to clarify your saying the only possible error is if one of string value in the table is greater then 1gb in size?

Comment: Yes. You might get other errors of course such as out of disc space but this won't cause data loss. It would be rolled back.

Comment: I see, Im most worried about truncation issues, In sql server I went to design view changed the datatype from varchar to nvarchar and it recreated the table. Didnt seem to get errors? Is that the right way to change the datatype?

Comment: I don't tend to use the GUI for this sort of change as it often ends up rebuilding the whole table unnecessarily. An `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` is often faster.

Comment: Yes that makes sense I think i will use the alter statement from here on in thanks for the advice :)